# Is there a way to know whether a certain dependency is compiled in the gradle file by returning a boolean

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

So the case is this, in the build.gradle file in the dependency structure I have

```
dependencies {
    compile 'A'
    compile 'B'
}
```

However I want people to be able to compile either just A or just B, is there a way to know for instance whether the dependency A was used by returning a global boolean that can be used somewhere else, in a gradle task?

so in other words

```
if (A was compiled) {
      compile A;
} else {
      exclude A;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want optional dependencies?

Comment: because i have a task that needs to know whether the particular dependency was included or not, the task is basically building a jar

Comment: Still don't get it...  Is this to build a fat jar?  So you want to exclude some dependencies sometimes from the jar?

Comment: Yes, that is it, I'm just trying to exclude some dependencies if they are not used from the fat jar

Comment: Have you looked at the shadow plugin? https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow

Comment: Especially calling `exclude` based on a condition (instead of trying to change dependencies based on a condition

Comment: used the exclude version to do what i needed. one thing that i saw is because i was pulling from maven the dependencies as aar, if you don't define transitive = true it doesn't know how to get the transitive dependencies by itself. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80989

Comment: Are 'A' and 'B' sub-projects in your build? If you could expand the question more I might be able to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get all compile dependencies like this:

```
def compile = configurations.compile.allDependencies*.with{"$it.group:$it.name:$it.version".toString()}
```

It would return list of all dependencies in `group:name:version` format. Then you could just use:

```
if("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.7" in compile) {
     println "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.7 was compiled"
}
```